# What is a good translation of ‘never mind’?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

What would be a good translation of *never mind*? I mean the following sense: If you're about to say something, but then realize that you no longer need to say that or no longer require a response to that, which you are about to say, you'd tell the person *never mind* to indicate this.

For me *ne gravas* comes to mind. Does this seem like a good choice or are there other/better possibilities?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know:

> Ne gravas.

which basically means:

> It's not important.

which in my opinion is close enough.

Comment: Yes, that's what I already mentioned, but good to know that this seems close enough. I am wondering, however, whether there are other options.

Comment: But you are asking multiple questions and one of them is "does this seem like a good choice" regarding "ne gravas". This is what Lyubomir just answered. If you just want other options, please change you question.

Comment: @LaStranga You're right, but to me it seemed Lyubomir wrote his answer as if I were unfamiliar with *ne gravas*, hence my response. I never said or meant to imply that it wasn't a useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Everything mentioned so far seems like a good choice, I just want to add that "forgesu, forgesu" or "forgesu tion" is pretty common in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

*Ne gravas* or *ne maltrankviliĝu* but I would personally say *ne aŭskultu min*.